# Flutter cubit states not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

**lib/services/data_services.dart**

```
class DataServices{
    String baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api";

    Future<List<DataModel>> getInfo() async{
        var apiUrl = '/getplaces';
        http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl+apiUrl));
        try{
          if(res.statusCode == 200){
            List<dynamic> list = json.decode(res.body);
            print(list);
            return list.map((e) => DataModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
          } else{
            return <DataModel>[];
          }
        } catch(e){
          print(e);
          return <DataModel>[];
        }
    }
}
```

**lib/cubit/app_cubits.dart**

```
class AppCubits extends Cubit<CubitStates>{
    AppCubits({required this.data}) : super(InitialState()){
      emit(WelcomeState());
    } 
    final DataServices data;
    late final places;

    void getData() async{
      try{
        emit(LoadingState());
        places = await data.getInfo();
        emit(LoadedState(places));
      } catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
}
```

**lib/cubit/app_cubit_states.dart**

```
abstract class CubitStates extends Equatable{ }

class InitialState extends CubitStates{
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadingState extends CubitStates{
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadedState extends CubitStates{
  LoadedState(this.places);
  final List<DataModel> places;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [places];
}

class WelcomeState extends CubitStates{
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

**lib/pages/home_page.dart**

```
if(state is LoadedState){
              var info = state.places;
              print(info);
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    //Menu
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70, left: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30, color: Colors.black54),
                          Expanded(child: Container()),
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30,),

                    //Discover
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: AppLargeText(text: "Discover"),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 20,),

                    //Tabbar
                    Container(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: TabBar(
                          labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                          controller: _tabController,
                          labelColor: Colors.black,
                          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                          isScrollable: true,
                          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                          indicator: CircleTabIndicator(color: AppColors.mainColor, radius: 4),
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(text: "Places",),
                            Tab(text: "Inspiration",),
                            Tab(text: "Emotions",),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ) 
                    ),

                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      height: 300,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      child: TabBarView(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        children: [
                          ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: info.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                              // print(info[index].img);
                              return Container( 
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 10),
                                width: 200,
                                height: 300,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(info[index].img),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  )
                                ),
                              );
                            }, 
                          ),
                          
                          Text("Screen2"),
                          Text("Screen3"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                      
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),

                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          AppLargeText(text: "Explore more", size: 22,),
                          AppText(text: "See all", color: AppColors.textColor1,)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10,),

                    Container(
                      height: 120,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 4,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                                width: 80,
                                height: 80,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage("img/"+images.keys.elementAt(index)),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  )
                                ),
                              ),

                              SizedBox(height: 10,),

                              Container(
                                child: AppText(
                                  text: images.values.elementAt(index),
                                  color: AppColors.textColor2,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        );
                      }),
                    )
                    
                  ], 
                ),
              );
```

In this Flutter program, I would like to load the places in the loaded state and when I try to print out `info` it only shows the empty array from the homepage instead of fetching data from the database phpMyAdmin. May I ask how to correctly fetch from database in the homepage in order to display on the page?

Comment: Are you able to log the fetched data from your service?

Comment: Yes it prints out data from service

Comment: Is your cubit able to log the fetched data from your service?

Comment: The data service is able to print out the fetched data

Comment: It's either you add print statement after you fetch the `places` from `data.getInfo()` or the suggested way is to create a [BlocObserver](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttercountertutorial?id=blocobserver) which will manage the logs for you.

Comment: I would like to print out the ```info``` correctly in the homepage in order to display on the screen

Comment: ```list.map((e) => DataModel.fromJson(e)).toList()``` returns nothing